# Clone directory and swap images

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

- I have a directory with html files and one image file
- I have a second directory with dozens of image files

For each image in the second directory, I need to clone the entire first directory and replace the image in that directory with the one from the second. As well as change the reference to the first image in the html file.

so before:

```
root
│
├───foo
│   ├───index.html
│   └───lorem.png
│
├───images
│   ├───ipsum
│   ├───dolor
│   ├───sit
│   ├───amet
│   ├───consectetur
│   └───adipiscing
```

and then after:

```
root
│
├───foo
│   ├───index.html
│   └───lorem.png
│
├───foo-ipsum
│   ├───index.html
│   └───ipsum.png
│
├───foo-dolor
│   ├───index.html
│   └───dolor.png
│
├───foo-sit
│   ├───index.html
│   └───sit.png
│
├───foo-amet
│   ├───index.html
│   └───amet.png
│
├───foo-consectetur
│   ├───index.html
│   └───consectetur.png
│
├───foo-adipiscing
│   ├───index.html
│   └───adipiscing.png
```

Comment: pluse 1 for excellent visual definition of your problem, but minus 1 for no attempt to solve your problem. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, you're expected to show an attempt to solve your problem and include relevant error messages from your testing. Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you're serious that you have to do this with `/bin/sh`, please include a tag for your OS or explain that you want a completely backwards-compatible solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a designer, and I didn't really know the first place to start. I've been doing it manually, and couldn't find a similarly-described issue to work off of.

Comment: as  you're using OSX, you don't really want to use `sh`. change your tag to `bash` and you may be more feedback. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written this script that does exactly what you need, including the modification of the html files. You have to provide the name of the "template dir", in your example "foo", as a parameter when you call the script: `bash script.bash foo`

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || {
    echo "You MUST provide the template dir as a parameter."
    exit -1
}

[[ -d $1 ]] || {
    echo "The template directory ($1) doesn't exist!"
    exit -1
}

template="$1"
template_img="$(ls $template | grep \.png)"
regex="(.*)\.png"

for f in $(ls images); do
    [[ $f =~ $regex ]] || continue

    name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    mkdir $name && {
        cp $template/index.html images/$f $name
        sed -i -e "s/$template_img/${name}.png/"  $name/index.html
    }
done
```

Comment: A lot of bad stuff in here: let's start with the most important ones: don't parse the output of `ls` and use more quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly for me. Now I'm a bit closer to understanding all of this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, try something like this:

```
# for each image
for file in images; do
    # get base name: i.e. image.png -> image
    base=$(echo $file | sed 's/.png//')
    # create desired dir foo.image
    mkdir "foo-${base}"
    # copy correct stuff to the dir
    cp index.html "foo-${base}/"
    mv "images/$file" "foo-${base}/"
end
# remove image dir
rmdir images/
```

When you run into issues, post more details, we'll be glad to help. You basically only need to construct a syntactically correct for loop.

Hint: You can either loop over the filenames using `$(ls dir)` (not advised) or use the `find` command in combination with the `exec` option (preferred). You can then put the 4 commands inside the loop in a bash function and call it using find's exec.

Comment: Why is it not recommended to use `$(ls dir)`? I find it much cleaner to use than the `find` alternative.

Comment: @gdrooid: 1. because it fails miserably if a filename contains a space (or a glob); 2. because it spawns a subshell and forks an external command; 3. because the output of `ls` is meant to be human-readable and, as such, is not machine-readable; 4. because it's easier, shorter and safer to use Bash's glob mechanism.